# Navigation Controller from Storyboard inherit from root controller (iOS11)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, ios11

In my app, I have a navigation controller (N1), controlling a tableview controller (T1) with a search bar.
When the search bar becomes active, a new navigation controller (N2) is presented from the storyboard to display the search results. (see image)

[image: storyboard]

This worked perfectly fine, until iOS 11, where the search bar is moved from the tableview header to the navigation bar.

A *partial* solution is to differentiate between OS versions, as follows:

```
-(void)initSearchController{
    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableSearchResultsNavController"];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
        //searchResultsController.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    }
}
```

However, because of the new position of the search bar in iOS 11, as soon as the search results are displayed, the search box disappears, since it is part of the navigation bar that has been replaced by the alien storyboard navcontroller.

I also modified a method, that is called when the search bar becomes active, as follows, but still the search bar disappears:

```
// Called when the search bar becomes first responder
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self updateFilteredContentForSearchString:searchString];
    if (self.searchController.searchResultsController) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController;

        SearchResultsTableViewController *vc = (SearchResultsTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;

        //my attempt, to no avail
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            vc.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;

        } else {
           vc.searchController=self.searchController;
        }

        vc.searchResults = self.searchResults;
        [vc.tv reloadData];
    }
}
```

What would be the approach to solve this? I want the app to remain compatible with pre-11 OS's (at least iOS10).

Do I have to completely rework this mechanism (if yes, how?), or is there just a simple line of code that would simply tell the controller N2 to also display the search bar?

Thanks for your insights